# Right way to use @Produce method

Tags: java, javafx-2, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm trying to combine CDI (weld-se 2) and JavaFX and I want to annotate my controller class with custom created annotation so this class creation is managed using my factory method. I suppose that is should looks like below but this code is not working. Could you possibly advice what should be changed?

*Annotation:*

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
@Qualifier
public @interface FXMLManaged {
}
```

*Factory class:*

```
public class FXMLManagedProducer {
    @Produces @FXMLManaged
    public <T> T getFXMLManagedInstance(Class<T> type) {
        return type.newInstance();
    }
}
```

*Controller class:*

```
@FXMLManaged
public class NewsListView {
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing stack traces?

Comment: This definitely should not work.

Comment: LightGuard, there is no stack trace, weld just doen't call the factory method when creating annotated controller.

Comment: John Ament, probably you know what should be changed in the code so it will work?

Comment: Can you please show some code of the class where NewListView is injected? Is this class created in the CDI context?

Comment: First of all you need to create a Weld-Container to use CDI. Here are some examples:

   http://java.dzone.com/articles/fxml-javafx-powered-cdi-jboss
   http://blog.matthieu.brouillard.fr/2012/08/fxml-javafx-powered-by-cdi-jboss-weld_6.html

There is a work-in-progress CDI API for JavaFX in development. It will be part of DataFX. You can find some news here:

   http://www.guigarage.com/2013/05/designing-javafx-business-applications-part-2/

Comment: @Slam I can't, because what you have is completely off base.  You cannot inject a type parameter in to a method without there being a producer for it.  CDI isn't meant to be a factory for creating objects, and using it as such is defeating the purpose of CDI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to mix CDI Extensions with producers. First, if you want to have a producer, the factory method should return a `NewsListView`, not a generic type. Using `@Producer` along with a qualifier annotation will bind with the annotated type. So there is no need to annotate `NewsListView` with `@FXMLManaged`. Then you inject your `NewsListView` somewhere in a bean.

Producing the view:

```
public class FXMLManagedProducer {
    @Produces @FXMLManaged
    public NewsListView getFXMLManagedInstance() {
        return new NewsListView();
    }
}
```

Using the producer:

```
public class SomeBean {
    @Inject @FXMLManaged
    NewsListView view;
}
```

But my guess is that this is not what you are looking for. I think you might want to create a [CDI Extension](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html)

```
public class YourExtension implements Extension {

    <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat) {
        if(pat.getAnnotatedType().isAnnotationPresent(FXMLManaged.class)) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
    } 
}
```

This way you would process your annotated `NewsListView`. You may want to have a look at other methods to hook into the lifecycle, so you can create the bean and inject dependencies if neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create a Weld-Container to use CDI. Here are some examples:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/fxml-javafx-powered-cdi-jboss
   http://blog.matthieu.brouillard.fr/2012/08/fxml-javafx-powered-by-cdi-jboss-weld_6.html

There is a work-in-progress CDI API for JavaFX in development. It will be part of DataFX. You can find some news here:

http://www.guigarage.com/2013/05/designing-javafx-business-applications-part-2/